# How do Shias perform the taslim (final salam) in prayer?

Tags: salat, shiism

When visiting Iran, I noticed that people performed [taslim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taslim) differently than I'm used to.  Basically, what I'm used to is:

1. Look right and say *assalamu alaikum wa rahmat Allah*.
2. Look left and say *assalamu alaikum wa rahmat Allah*.

This is as indicated on the Wikipedia page.

What I saw in Iran was something along the lines of holding one's right hand up and moving it up and down, looking right and left, and saying a longer version of *assalamu alaikum wa rahmat Allah* three times.

I'm hoping to clarify what's going on here.

**Question**: How do Shias perform the taslim (final salam) in prayer?

Answer (score 1):

## After Tashahud, a Shia recites Taslim.

---

Taslim in Shia Islam is:

> السلام عليك أيها النبي و رحمة الله وبركاته، السلام علينا وعلى عباد اللّٰه الصالحين، السلام عليكم ورحمة الله وبركاته
>
> **Transliteration:** *Assalaamu Alaika Ayyuhan Nabiyyu Wa Rahmat Ullahi Wa Barkaat Hu, Assalaamu Alaina Wa Ala Ibaad Illahis Soaalihiin, Assalamu Alaikum wa Rahmat Ullahi Wa Barkaat*
>
> **Translation:** *(O Prophet! God’s peace, blessing and grace be upon you, God’s peace be upon us, and upon those who perform prayers and upon pious servants of God, God's peace blessing and grace be upon you/ believers)*

After this one instantly does **Rafa-Yadain/ Raise hands three times each time uttering [Takbir](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Takbir)**, with this final action and recitation one’s salaah is complete and one exits from it.

---

Source: [welcomtoshiaislam.blogspot](https://welcometoshiaislam.blogspot.co.uk/2015/04/how-to-perform-salah-namaz-prayers-as.html?m=1)

Comment: Mashaa Allah, a helpful answer. Jazakallahu khairun!